# python smtplib module's smtp_ssl connect method is not working

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib

email address is not the one that I mentioned here.

This is the code:

```
    import dns.resolver
    import smtplib
    email_address = "BC@xyz.com"
    domain_name = email_address.split('@')[1]
    records = dns.resolver.resolve(domain_name, 'MX')
    mxRecord = records[0].exchange
    mxRecord = str(mxRecord)
    print(mxRecord)
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL()
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.connect(mxRecord,465)
```

The error that I am getting on server.connect() is:

```
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
new_socket = super()._get_socket(host, port, timeout)
return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> records = dns.resolver.resolve(domain_name, 'MX')
> ...
> server.connect(mxRecord,465)
> ```

Port 465 and 587 are used for contacting the mail server of a provider for the customers of this provider. Accessing these ports also usually requires authentication.

A mail server announced by an MX record expects instead connections on the standard SMTP port 25. These connections must be done in plain, not SSL. To upgrade to SSL the [STARTTLS command](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls) must be issued on the plain connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I was initially using the standard SMTP port 25 and in plain, but I wanted the secure connection that's why I used SSL, and faced the issue. I understand the second part of your answer. Can you please elaborate more on the first part because the same code worked fine with SMTP(plain).

Comment: @rohanpatel: what do you mean with *"the same code worked fine with SMTP(plain)"*? Did you use plain SMTP on port 465? Should not work. Did you use plain SMTP on port 25? That's expected since it is announced as MX.

Comment: No, I changed the port to 25. But in the host field of connect I used the mxRecord only.

Comment: So, should I use STARTTLS command instead of this for secure connection ?

Comment: @rohanpatel: *"No, I changed the port to 25. But in the host field of connect I used the mxRecord only."* - like I said, this is the expected behavior. *" should I use STARTTLS command instead of this for secure connection ?"* - yes.

Comment: I was using port 587 and starttls and it's working fine for sending an email to valid email address. But when I use the same protocol for verifying an email address by including " server.send(sender)  server.rcpt(reciever)" it is giving  code 250 inspite of having a wrong reciever email address. Can you share your thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: @rohanpatel: This is a completely different question., please ask it as new one with full details. And again, 587 is not the port used for public delivery to the domain but for use by authenticated clients of the mail provider to send from their domain.